# ngrx for User Profile CRUD operations

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngrx

I'm a bit new to the world of using Redux (and in-turn, `ngrx` for Angular/Ionic projects) for state management, but I've done a few sample tutorials and really like the methodology, and how persistent state is.

However, no example I've found so far covers some of the questions I have. Given the `Profile` model:

```
export class Profile {
   public id?: string;
   public name?: string;
   public interests?: Interest[];
   public jobs?: Job[];
}
```

I have a few questions if anyone could point me in the right direction:

1. What's the best way to approach creating stores and state? Should I create one mega-store that does everything from checking authentication, to adding/removing `jobs` or `interests`?
2. Is there anyway I can share this `Profile` state object between stores?
3. Should I manage the state of `interests` and `jobs` separately, then use an action to update the user's profile when it's ready to be synced, and grab those values from the app's state?
4. Can an action from one store (say, `SaveInterests` in `InterestsActions`) call an action from another store (say, `SaveInterests => SaveProfile`)?

Answer (score 0):

In a typical redux or ngrx application you'll only see one store. Your application's state will be represented as one big JavaScript object. For more info see the redux docs [Three Principles](https://redux.js.org/introduction/threeprinciples) and [Core Concepts](https://redux.js.org/introduction/coreconcepts).

The structure of the your store should be normalized, see the redux docs [Normalizing State Shape](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/normalizingstateshape) or the post [NgRx: Normalizing state](https://medium.com/@timdeschryver/ngrx-normalizing-state-d3960a86a3aa). Meaning it would look something like the following:

```
{
  profiles: {...},
  interests: {...},
  jobs: {...},
}
```

Once the data is stored in the store, it becomes available to the whole application.

You won't be able to dispatch an action from a reducer if that's what you're asking. But you could dispatch multiple actions or use the same action in multiple reducers (an action gets send to every reducer in your application).

Comment: I read through it, still doesn't really address my concern about actions for, say `interests` needing to sync into the user profile.